# How to retrieve position of a sprite by name

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I made a loop which creates multiple sprites `(SKSpriteNode *spriteButton)` and assigns to them different names `(@"1", @"2", @"3", etc)` and different positions on the screen.

Now, how can I retrieve the position.x and position.y of a given sprite in the series, lets's say sprite number 1?

Thanks

Comment: Did you read the docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `childNodeWithName:` method is the one you are looking for. For more information, [read the `SKNode` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKNode/childNodeWithName:).

Comment: Thanks but it does not seem to work... [spriteButton childNodeWithName:@"1"].position.y always return zero in my case..

Comment: @jeddi Do you understand the child-parent-sibling hierarchy system SpriteKit works in? You need to use that method with the parent of `spriteButton`.

Comment: Got it. Fantastic. Thank you. I was using [spriteButton childNodeWithName:@"1"] rather than [self childNodeWithName:@"1"]